# Delete all items from SharePoint Online List Using SSIS

Tags: sharepoint, ssis, sharepoint-online, kingswaysoft

I have a task to update SharePoint Lists every day using SSIS. Before adding new data to Share Point I need to delete old elements of the list. I'm using SQL Server Data as a source. And I'm Using Kingswaysoft Share Point drivers on SSIS.

When I try to perform. it is not deleting the old records
What I have done

Uploaded data first and performed delete

[image]

for delete, I have followed below strategy

[image]

but delete operation is not performed after the package execution
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach would be to use our [Premium File Transfer Task component](https://www.kingswaysoft.com/products/ssis-productivity-pack/help-manual/premium-file-pack/premium-file-transfer-task) which is provided with our [SSIS Integration Toolkit for SharePoint](https://www.kingswaysoft.com/products/ssis-integration-toolkit-for-microsoft-sharepoint). In the Premium File Transfer Task, you can set the action to delete files and then choose SharePoint as the Destination Connection Manager.

Don't hesitate to [reach out to our Support team](https://www.kingswaysoft.com/about-us/contact-us) if you have any more questions.

[image: Screenshot of Premium File Transfer Task set up to Delete Files and Choose SharePoint as the Destination Connection Manager]

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. It is asking the directory path. what should we suppose to give as I'm not able to find the same list in this component. it listed only SharePoint->Documents, >ShareDoce, >Site Assets, > Site Pages, >Temapltesm > Test Library

Comment: Or can you please specify the pattern of the directory path of a list ?